# MVC Best approaching reading data

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I was wondering what's the best approaching to read data in ASP.NET.

**Method 1:**

In the controller:

```
public ActionResult CatPerfomanceReportCreate(string dateStart, string dateEnd)
        {
            ViewBag.DateStart = dateStart;
            ViewBag.DateEnd = dateEnd;
            return View();
        }
```

and the View:

```
    @{
        var readData = MyDataClass.GetData(ViewBag.DateStart, ViewBag.DateEnd)
    }
..
..
..
<table>,,,,,<table>
```

**Method 2:**

In the controller:

```
public ActionResult CatPerfomanceReportCreate(string dateStart, string dateEnd)
        {
            ViewBag.Data = MyDataClass.GetData(dateStart, dateEnd);
            return View();
        }
```

and the View:

```
    @{
        List<MyDataClass> data = ViewBag.Data;
    }
..
..
..
<table>,,,,,<table>
```

Method 1 read the heavy data in the View and Method 2 in the controller.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither.

**Method2** is slightly better than **Method1** because it comply with the **Dumb View** method. Both of those method make use of the **ViewBag** dynamic which can but not intended to save information about your information you want to present to the user. Strongly Type elements in most cases are much preferred than dynamics and giving you the full force of the compiler behind it.

Let me suggest **Method3** that is much better suited method for MVC. It is creating a Model of the data you want to use in your View and use it.

**Model:**

```
public class CatPerfomanceReport
{
    public string DateStart { get; set; }
    public string DateEnd { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller:**

```
public ActionResult CatPerfomanceReportCreate(string dateStart, string dateEnd)
{
    var model = new CatPerfomanceReport
    {
        DateStart = dateStart,
        DateEnd = dateEnd
    };
    return View(model);
}
```

**Partial of View:**

```
@model CatPerfomanceReport

<h1>Start: @Model.DateStart</h1>
<h1>End: @Model.DateEnd</h1>
```

Comment: Ok... nice, but my question is... Where I read the heavy data??? Controller or View?

Comment: Controller - Populating model. View - Only displaying.